# Is it possible to defer reaping of background processes in bash?

Tags: bash, background-process, process-management, wait, zombie-process

If I just run `sleep 1 &` in bash, the `sleep` process will get reaped almost instantly after it dies. This happens whether job control is enabled or disabled. Is there a way I can make bash hold off on reaping the process until I do something like `wait` or `fg`? E.g.:

```bash
sleep 1 &
sleep 2
ps -ef | grep defunct # I want this to show the sleep 1 process
wait
ps -ef | grep defunct # But now it should be gone
```

Comment: I don't understand. Are you actually talking about `sleep 1`? Isn't it normal that it will be gone after one second?

Comment: @TomYan, yes and no. When a process dies, its parent gets the SIGCHLD signal, which prompts it to call `wait()` to fetch the exit status of the child. Before that happens, the dead process is still lying around in the process list as a so-called zombie process. You usually don't see them, since most programs that fork children  just clean them up immediately.

Comment: Shell scripting is relatively high level and the shell does a lot of tidying up as it goes. If you don't want this level of support you're going to need to use a programming language such as Python, Perl, C, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would want to, but you can interpose another process to reap the child, then pause that process so it cannot handle the SIGCHLD signal. Eg:

```bash
bash -c 'sleep 1 & kill -STOP $$' &
pid=$!
sleep 2
ps -ef|grep defunct
ps f
kill -CONT $pid
```

The `ps f` output showing the `T` and `Z` states would be

```
 8023 pts/2    S+     0:00  \_ /bin/bash mytest
 8024 pts/2    T+     0:00      \_ bash -c sleep 1 & kill -STOP $$
 8026 pts/2    Z+     0:00      |   \_ [sleep] <defunct>
 8029 pts/2    R+     0:00      \_ ps f
```

Comment: I suppose the approach will be subjected a race?

Comment: Sure. It is just a proof of concept since we don't know what the OP really wants to do. You can make it more robust by giving the pause action within the child to the parent, e.g. with `bash -c '(kill -STOP $$; exec sleep 1) & wait' &`